# Excel 2013 and 2016 flicker when ScreenUpdating = False and creating a new hidden workbook

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, excel-2013

If you run the code below in Excel 2013 or Excel 2016 then it will cause Excel to flicker.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to stop the flickering?

```
Sub FlickerTestMain()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    FlickerTestHelper

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub FlickerTestHelper()
    Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook, newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set currentWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set newWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    newWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    currentWorkbook.Activate
    newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1:Z10000").Value2 = "test"
    newWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a hunch it's your sheet names? Change them from `ActiveWorkbook` (which I believe are reserved words in VBA) to just like `mySheet1` and `mySheet2`. It's very confusing to see `ActiveWorkbook.Activate`, especially since `Activeworkbook` is its own variable.  It doesn't flicker really for me though, Excel 2016. Is it really bad flickering? or a quick one?

Comment: I've renamed the activeWorkbook variable to currentWorkbook to avoid confusion. I am not doing anything with sheet names so I'm not sure how its relevant. This example only takes about a second to run, but you definitely see flickering. I have tested this with Excel 2013 and 2016 on both Win7 and Win10. The flicker is more apparent if Excel is not maximized. Also it is more apparent in Win10 since the window borders have effects like shadowing. One easy way to tell if it is flickering or not is to look at the Caption bar text in Excel (for example where it says "Book1 - Excel")

Comment: Quick question - can you have another computer run this macro, and see if there's flickering? It may be less of a VBA issue and perhaps more of a computer resources issue?

Comment: I don't even think Excel has any control over that - the flickering is coming from the focus switching between the windows.

Comment: I've tested on my main computer (Win10) and two virtual machines (Win7 and Win10). It definitely has to do with Excel being Single Document Interface (SDI) in that Excel 2013 and 2016 create new windows for each workbook. But since ScreenUpdating is an application setting you would hope that it would deal with a situation like this. I've tried a few WinApi functions like LockWindowUpdate as well as SetWindowPos to TopMost but neither seemed to work.

Comment: You could try subclassing the message queue instead and just prevent it from redrawing the non-client area.  No idea if that would work or not.

Comment: how would I go about 'subclassing the message queue'? Is there a reference that you could point me to?